# Как сделать наблюдаемыми геттеры объекта, который в массиве

Tags: reactjs, mobx

Делаю следующее:

```
    MyClass:{
val1: (...)
val2: (...)
get val1: ƒ ()
set val1: ƒ (x)
get val2: ƒ ()
set val2: ƒ (x)
}

@observable x = [];
const a = new MyClass();

@action add = () => this.x.push(a);
```

При записи нового значения в val1 или val2 не срабатывает ререндер в компоненте, так как mobx это дело не отслеживает. Никак не соображу как заставить mobx следить за ними и перерисовывать компонент с новыми значениями. Подскажите плиз.

Comment: Сделайте observable поля в MyClass

Comment: А есть варианты без модификации класса?

Comment: Если нельзя менять класс, то можете сделать observable-обертку над MyClass, в которой observable будет переменная, содержащая объект MyClass и action и calculate, повторяющие геттеры и сеттеры MyClass

Comment: @DmitryKozlov оформите Ваш комментарий как ответ